# Loosening Tefillin Retzuot

Tags: tefilin, how-to

BH, I recently purchased a new pair of tefillin.

Does anyone have any tips for loosening new, stiff tefillin retzuot? Right now my retzuot practically cut into my skin. Over time, they will eventually become looser, but I was wondering if there were any quick tips or tricks.

Comment: Wearing them regularly?

Comment: don't wrap them so tightly?

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi - I do. And I mentioned that eventually they would become looser with wearing them for davening every morning. But my question is if there is a quicker way to loosen them.

Comment: How do you deal with new leather shoes which aren't so soft yet? This is no different.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would ask around before trying it myself, apparently [coating](http://www.wikihow.com/Soften-a-Leather-Belt) the tough leather with rubbing alcohol followed by a coating of petroleum jelly opens the pores and makes it softer.

Comment: I might be afraid that this method might hurt the retzuot. But thanks for the answer!!